# Ckeditor remove / disable Table properties and Cell properties dialogs

Tags: ckeditor4.x

I have ckeditor Table plugin and Quicktable plugin, too.
Can anybody help me how to remove or disable Table Properties  and Cell Properties dialogs only , and merge options (if user click with right mouse in table) ? ... as marks in screens bellow.  Many thanks for help.

[image: table properties]

[image]

Comment: I wont that users will create simple table only.... so I need to disable these options.

Comment: I have found solution here [link]ckeditor.com/forums/Support/How-to-edit-context-menu